# Javascript if else in document ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery

am new to javascript am looking for if else in document ready function

my html code is

```
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="hanu" id="Male" value="1" checked/> Male
  <input type="radio" name="hanu" id="Female" value="2" /> Female
</form>
```

Now am looking for javascript which we can run if we select male need to execute some on change function if we select female need to execute some other on change function

```
if (document.getElementById('Male').checked){
//some first change function
} else {
//some second change function
}
```

now the problem with am able to get first change function not able to second change function

Comment: You should call the same code again on change of radio button state. Look out for `onchange` event in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method proposed by Rory is perfectly valid.Here is another method using Jquery.I am calling the functions every time the option is clicked on.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Male").on('click',function(){
    alert("Male");
  });
  $("#Female").on('click',function(){
    alert("Female");
  });
  });
```

Here is a working [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/qpElCX4bxFBRRYwPe9jt?p=preview)

Alternatively, you can also use the class on change function as Rory pointed out.

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" class="gender" name="hanu" id="Male" value="1" checked/> Male
<input type="radio" class="gender"  name="hanu" id="Female" value="2" /> Female
```

**JQuery**

```
 $(".gender").on('change',function(){
    alert("changed");
  });
```

Here is a working [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/iuKrJkoIKSi3zhWYz2CO?p=preview)

Comment: its working perfectly thanks a lot for the quick help "Satej S"

Comment: @HanumaiahT, you're welcome!Please do upvote answers that you think have helped you/answered the query , and do select an answer as accepted as well.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because the document.ready handler is only executed once in the page lifecycle (on load). Therefore there is no Javascript listening when the checkboxes you have are changed. You should hook to the `change` event to do that. Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $(':checkbox').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '1') { 
            // Male selected, do something...
        } else {
            // Female selected, do something else...
        }
    }).change(); // trigger a change so this code also runs on load
});
```

The `:checkbox` selector may be too generic for your actual production code, I just used it as an example. I would suggest you change it to something more specific, using a class perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

`document.ready` gets called only first time as page is loaded in order to get this again and again you should shift it to the function other than document.ready

Comment: can you suggest what is the other method

Comment: you can use this on OnChange event

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that your code is executed only once.

You need to bind change event for your elements:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).attr('id') == 'Male') {
            //do something
        } else if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).attr('id') == 'Female') {

        }
    });
})
```

Comment: `$(this).is(':checked')` is redundant as the radio that raised the event has to be checked in order to raise the `change` event

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the idea without JQuery:

```
document.getElementById('Male').onclick = function(){
alert('male clicked!');
}
```

you are binding the onclick event of the element to a javascript function which alerts a string...

Answer (score 0):

Pure javascript solution, and i strongly recommend to use form event, not input, give it a name, add event listener

```js
document.myform.onchange = function(event){
  alert(event.target.value);
}
```

```html
<form name="myform">
  <input type="radio" name="hanu" id="Male" value="1" checked/> Male
  <input type="radio" name="hanu" id="Female" value="2" /> Female
</form>
```